# Cannot connect to hornet dashboard via http://localhost:8081

Tags: hornet, hornet-dashboard

First of all thank you to everyone who was involved in making setting up a IOTA node and running it so simple. It's so simple in fact that the first (and only problem so far) is accessing the dashboard.

I followed the instructions on provided here: https://docs.iota.org/docs/hornet/1.1/tutorials/install-hornet-docker

From the CLI it looks like everything is up an running (LSMI/LMI: 3371904/3371904)

During the start-up it also showed:

> You can now access the dashboard using: http://localhost:8081

However, when I try to connect to it Safari and Chrome cannot reach the server.
(While I can access localhost:8888 for Jupyter for example).

I don't even know how to start the search for the error.
Any suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you expose port 8081. Port 8081 is used by the dashboard.

Something like -p 8081:8081 in the command. Something else that can work is right clicking and seeing if there are any console errors in the inspector

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried this:  by starting lets change the network mode and export the proper port,
docker run ...  --network=bridge -p 8081:8081  ... gohornet/hornet